# Set default date as last 7 days from present date in date slicer Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have date slicer which coming from 'date' column contains date from 1-1-2017 to present date. Currently date slicer shows min and max date but I want to set default date as last 7 days from present.

I want to show the default from/to date as last 7 days from present day like this.

[image: 1]

Constraints

- I can manually change the from/to date for previous days/month/year in the same date slider. Just default from/to date will be last 7 days.
- Example:

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

Select your slicer, then go to the filters pane, select Date, and choose relative date. This way you should be able to set the filter to the last "x" days.

Comment: But with this solution I can't change the days for previous dates.

Comment: Hi, it would be useful to know which version of Power BI you are using, as there might be different solutions to your problem. More recent versions include for example the possibility to use parameters with data type Date, or use date ranges in slicers